# Are there any bad consequences to using formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, forms, formtastic

This gem seems too good to be true. It's like the ultimate time-saver.

Have you guys run into any problems or limitations that I should be aware of before I commit to using it?

How is the performance? So much reflection on your models seems a bit scary, even though I admit it saves so much time ;)

I'm just curious if any problems that might result from using it before I charge ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a great library but it does generate a lot of markup. Before diving into any one technology be sure to check out the alternatives. The latest hot one I've seen is [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know about the alternative. I'm going to check that one out too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The only possible limitation i can think off is that the markup of formtastic is fixed. Mind you: if you don't mind, it is fantastic. It is really awesome to get started with.

The advantage of simple_form over formtastic is that you can modify the markup to your needs. This can be handy if your designer likes your fields to be grouped inside `div` instead of `li`. The downside of simple_form is that it doesn come with any standard layout (css). That makes formtastic much easier to start off with. Because the API is nearly identical, if needed, you can very easily switch to simple_form if needed.

I have not encountered any negative impact on performance, with either.